# jquery ui button not being styled

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a js function that inserts a form in response to a button click. At the bottom of the form is a button also added by the function. Somehow the new button does not inherit the ui css even if I add the ui-button class. Any help will be appreciated:

```
var addSite = function(){
var addForm ='<br><input id="site-db" class="manage-sites" type="text" placeholder="Domain" onfocus="this.placeholder=\'\'"  onblur="this.placeholder = \'Domain\'"><br>' +
'<input id="site-table" class="manage-sites" type="text" placeholder="Table" onfocus="this.placeholder=\'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'Table\'"><br>' +
'<input id="site-IP" class="manage-sites" type="text" placeholder="IP Address" onfocus="this.placeholder=\'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'IP Address\'"><br>' +
'<input id="site-Server" class="manage-sites" type="text" placeholder="Server" onfocus="this.placeholder=\'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'Server\'"><br>' +
'<input id="site-password" class="manage-sites" type="text" placeholder="Password" onfocus="this.placeholder=\'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'Password\'"><br>' +
'<button class="ui-button">Add to Datasites</button>';
$('#manage-sites').html(addForm);
}
```

Relevant(?) HTML. These buttons render properly:

```
<div id="tabs-7">
<!-- Manage Data Sites -->
<h1>Manage Data Sites</h1>
<br><br>
<button id="add-site">Add</button>
<button id="delete-site">Delete</button>
<button id="view-sites">View</button>
<div id="manage-sites" style="margin-top:20px; width:100%">

</div>
<script>
    $('#add-site').click(function(){
        addSite();  
    })

</script>


</div>
```

Comment: You are referencing `manage-sites` as an ID in your div, and as a class in your generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI styling for a button requires more than just the `ui-button` class. If you inspect the source for the jQuery buttons on [this demo page](http://jqueryui.com/button/) you'll notice that the buttons also have the following classes:

```
ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all
```

You could tackle this two ways:

1 - Add the classes manually: `<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">blah</button>`

2 - After the html has been appended, call jQuery UI's button() method on the newly created element (I used [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) here).

```
$('#manage-sites').html(addForm)
    .find('.ui-button').button();
```

---

Full Demo

```js
$(function(){
    var addSite = function(){
        var addForm ='<br><input id="site-db" class="manage-sites" type="text" placeholder="Domain" onfocus="this.placeholder=\'\'"  onblur="this.placeholder = \'Domain\'"><br>' +
        '<input id="site-table" class="manage-sites" type="text" placeholder="Table" onfocus="this.placeholder=\'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'Table\'"><br>' +
        '<input id="site-IP" class="manage-sites" type="text" placeholder="IP Address" onfocus="this.placeholder=\'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'IP Address\'"><br>' +
        '<input id="site-Server" class="manage-sites" type="text" placeholder="Server" onfocus="this.placeholder=\'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'Server\'"><br>' +
        '<input id="site-password" class="manage-sites" type="text" placeholder="Password" onfocus="this.placeholder=\'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'Password\'"><br>' +
        '<button class="ui-button">Add to Datasites</button>';
        $('#manage-sites').html(addForm)
         .find('.ui-button').button();
    };
    
    $('#add-site').click(function(){
        addSite(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-7">
<!-- Manage Data Sites -->
<h1>Manage Data Sites</h1>
<br><br>
<button id="add-site">Add</button>
<button id="delete-site">Delete</button>
<button id="view-sites">View</button>
<div id="manage-sites" style="margin-top:20px; width:100%">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Must be a side-effect of appending to appending  as I have a function that finds all buttons in the page and applies .button()

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing `manage-sites` as an ID in your div, and as a class in your generated HTML. If `manage-sites` is defined as an ID (i.e. `#manage-sites` instead of `.manage-sites`) in your CSS, then your div will pick up the style but your generated HTML will not.

Assign a different ID to your div, and change `manage-sites` to a class.

Comment: I have both a class and an ID "manage-sites". I should be able to do that without issue. filoxo's solution above works well, but I will see what happens if I change the ID on the div.  I use this practice quite  a bit though and have not run into issues.